Find positions of keyword in GZ'ipped file
I'm trying to identify parts of a MySQL DB that take most space in GZipped dumps that I need to frequently save and restore so that I can archive some tables partially.
I have a suspicion that different tables are compressed better or worse depending on their content so their uncompressed size is not very relevant here.
Is there any way I can map CREATE TABLE or INSERT statements in the DB dump to the file positions in the .sql.gz file? Something like
gunzip <db.sql.gz | grep 'insert into' | print {0}
where {0} is the current position of the db.sql.gz file that gunzip is reading from

You can use grep -n to find the line numbers in the uncompressed data, but this will not help you identify it in the compressed file. It'd probably be much easier to dump tables into their own files, package that up as a single .gz, then use gzip -l on it to get compressed/uncompressed size.

but, that's not how lempel-ziv variants as used in gzip (or most other compression methods, really) work; the data that gets produced at some point is the result of all the previous input (assuming you don't have a stream reset coming in before), not of a single position.

It's terribly inefficient, but you can try feeding partial data to gunzip and see how much comes out:
#!/bin/bash

filename="${1}"
filesize=$(stat -c %s "${filename}")

zipped=0
unzipped=0
step=1024

for ((zipped=step; zipped < filesize; zipped+=step))
do
    unzipped=$(head -c "${zipped}" "${filename}" | gunzip 2> /dev/null | wc --bytes)
    printf "zipped %d = %d unzipped\n" "${zipped}" "${unzipped}"
done

And the output would be something like:
zipped 1024 = 1560 unzipped
zipped 2048 = 5731 unzipped
zipped 3072 = 14369 unzipped
zipped 4096 = 20260 unzipped
zipped 5120 = 23206 unzipped
zipped 6144 = 26740 unzipped
zipped 7168 = 31636 unzipped
zipped 8192 = 39563 unzipped
zipped 9216 = 48645 unzipped
zipped 10240 = 56667 unzipped
[…]

That way you can build a rough relation between zipped vs. unzipped data offsets. Determining the byte offsets of your SQL statements should not be hard (grep can print byte offsets too, or any editor would show them).
But its terribly slow since it will gunzip the same data countless times. I attempted to do this in one go like you suggested, but the results are terribly inaccurate due to buffering in the pipes and inside gunzip itself.
So for an efficient and accurate implementation, you might have to do this in a programming language where you have direct control over the (de)compression algorithm.
Or, if you are looking to find a specific byte offset in the unzipped data, you could implement a divide-and-conquer / binary search algorithm, to find just that single offset alone.

You could make this faster with a gztool index.

@StephenKitt yeah I roughly remember there were some utilities for it, but my search came up empty. I'll leave it to someone else to answer

Nngh, I'm not at all sure I can reason about this properly, but I wonder how well this maps into the compressibility of the individual tables, given that the compression could look for similarities between the tables, right ...? Unless the tables are large enough compared to how far back gzip looks for relations?

dd will print info about what it's seen to stderr when it receives a SIGUSR1, so you can stick it in a pipeline right before gunzip and signal it when you see what you want to in gunzip's output. Quick proof of concept:
#!/bin/bash
mkfifo test.pipe
dd </dev/urandom >test.pipe &
DD_PID=$!
grep -abo --line-buffered foo test.pipe | while read
do
    kill -s USR1 $DD_PID
done

Example run:
% ./test.sh
31180+0 records in
31179+0 records out
15963648 bytes (16 MB, 15 MiB) copied, 0.111636 s, 143 MB/s
47355+0 records in
47354+0 records out
24245248 bytes (24 MB, 23 MiB) copied, 0.162628 s, 149 MB/s
95080+0 records in
95080+0 records out
48680960 bytes (49 MB, 46 MiB) copied, 0.279467 s, 174 MB/s
95702+0 records in
95702+0 records out
48999424 bytes (49 MB, 47 MiB) copied, 0.281052 s, 174 MB/s
126695+0 records in
126695+0 records out
64867840 bytes (65 MB, 62 MiB) copied, 0.358433 s, 181 MB/s
134752+0 records in
134752+0 records out
68993024 bytes (69 MB, 66 MiB) copied, 0.377993 s, 183 MB/s
137704+0 records in
137703+0 records out
70503936 bytes (71 MB, 67 MiB) copied, 0.385317 s, 183 MB/s
244929+0 records in
244929+0 records out
125403648 bytes (125 MB, 120 MiB) copied, 0.648341 s, 193 MB/s
283637+0 records in
283637+0 records out
145222144 bytes (145 MB, 138 MiB) copied, 0.743777 s, 195 MB/s
348024+0 records in
348023+0 records out
178187776 bytes (178 MB, 170 MiB) copied, 0.902988 s, 197 MB/s
^C
zsh: interrupt  ./test.sh

There's buffers all over the place -- each pipe probably has one allocated for you by the OS, and each program in the pipeline probably has one internally -- so these numbers won't be exact, but they should be enough to give you a rough idea of things.

The left-hand side of the pipe will be ahead of the right-hand side in terms of bytes transferred due to buffering in the pipe, so the numbers this gives will likely be larger than the sctual position would be.

Interesting. How do I close the pipe to restart the script? I tried it a few times and ended having to reboot the system. Also, which output comes from grep and which from dd? I don't see the usual grep print out of the found text either.

@AntonDuzenko To close the pipe, kill dd (with a deadly signal like SIGTERM or in an emergency SIGKILL) and delete the fifo. All of the output shown here is from dd, and appears on stderr; all of grep's output on stdout is going to read.

@ilkkachu Thanks, I was debating whether to mention it. I guess you're right it's probably worth it, so I added a note at the end to that effect.

The answer by @DanielWagner gave me an idea to use pv instead of dd. The biggest problem was to preserve the pv's output, so here's my best try:
pv -bt </media/sf_shared/daily-04.sql.gz | gunzip | mysql -u qwe -pasd zxc -v | grep -F 'CREATE TABLE' --line-buffered | awk '{print "\n"$3}'

This is the full version that prints both compressed size (roughly) and import time for each table in the dump.
`BannedUserComment`
`Bookings`
70,5MiB 0:01:09
`C_Accounting_Refund`
`C_AutoInvest`
`C_Balance_Relation_Balance`
78,5MiB 0:01:16
`C_Balance_Relation_LoanAuction`
80,0MiB 0:01:17
`C_Balance_Relation_LoanContract`
`C_Bookkeeping_Balancing`
82,5MiB 0:01:19
`C_Campagne_2015`
`C_Camt054`
`C_Casher_AddressAbroad`
`C_Casher_Notification`
`C_Casher_Relation_Casher`
`C_Company_Debt_Capacity`
`C_Company_Financials`
85,0MiB 0:01:21
`C_Company_Financials_Ebitda_Value`
86,5MiB 0:01:22
`C_Company_Financials_Ratio`

A shorter version that only prints the size and does not try to actually import the dump:
pv -bti 0.1 < /media/sf_shared/daily-04.sql.gz | gunzip | grep -F 'CREATE TABLE' --line-buffered | awk '{print "\n"$3}'
`BannedUserComment`
`Bookings`
70,5MiB
`C_Accounting_Refund`
`C_AutoInvest`
`C_Balance_Relation_Balance`
79,5MiB
`C_Balance_Relation_LoanAuction`
`C_Balance_Relation_LoanContract`
`C_Bookkeeping_Balancing`
`C_Campagne_2015`
`C_Camt054`
`C_Casher_AddressAbroad`
`C_Casher_Notification`
`C_Casher_Relation_Casher`
`C_Company_Debt_Capacity`
`C_Company_Financials`
84,5MiB
`C_Company_Financials_Ebitda_Value`
`C_Company_Financials_Ratio`

This, of course, only works for tables big enough to process longer than the pv's update interval
